# C# + БД MSSQL , показ в двух формах

Tags: c#

кому не трудно помогите, есть dbgriview на одной форме, в ней показывается view из БД,есть так же вторая форма, на которой тоже dbgriview . Не могу понять как сделать,чтобы к примеру, на первой форме нажали на машину, тыкнули на кнопку и  появилась вторая форма с информацией о этой машине, view об информации на второй грид я загрузил, как сделать, чтобы он показывался именно по id выбранной машины из первого grida. вот скрины.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Скрины . ViewCarsM это машины, ViewCars это информация о машине]

Comment: Код лучше вставить текстом.

Answer (score 0):

1. Обработчик события на главной форме DataGridView selectedChanged или doubleClick как удобно.
2. в этом обработчике находим выбранный элемент ID или что там у Вас и создаем либо показываем (если не создана) форму 2 предварительно подгрузив (вариантов масса либо сама форма подтягивает) данные в эту форму 2.